# Problems regarding header files in c++

Tags: c++, header

hello and good morning everyone! im new to c++ and just learnt the header files. I already tried many times to fix the error but when i include the header file in my main, i received an error " undefined reference to `IPhone::IPhone()'". Here is my header file. (im using DEV C++)

```
#ifndef IPHONE_H
#define IPHONE_H

class IPhone
{
    public :
    IPhone();
};
#endif
```

This is my cpp file (for the implementation of the header file)

```
#include "iphone.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

IPhone::IPhone()
{
    cout<< "object created ";
    
}
```

Lastly, this is may main to test the class

```
#include<iostream>
#include "iphone.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    IPhone phone1;
    return 0;
    
}
```

Thankyou in advance!

Comment: How did you compile your programs?

Comment: i run the program with dev C++

Comment: Are you using cmake, visual studio, ninja?

Comment: im using DEV C++ sir

Comment: The reason that people ask you about how you compile is because the error message indicates that your cpp file with `main()` is compiled, but the cpp file with the `IPhone` constructor is either not compiled or not linked. You must instruct your development environment to consider the latter cpp file as well. Perhaps you did not add it to the project?

Comment: i didnt know that i need to link it. I thought just by #include headerfile.h is sufficient to run the program. Thankyou sir for giving me solutions! i appreciate your time n effort